# Identity between functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions of one real variable. We want to show that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f = g$ on the interval $[a,b]$. I have shown that for any subinterval $[t_a,t_b] \subseteq [a,b]$ we have $\int_{t_a}^{t_b} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{t_a}^{t_b} g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$. Is it sufficient? Is there any variational way to justify this result?

Comment: What are $\,f,g\,$?! And $\,f\,$ must be at least differentiable, not only continuous...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f^\prime(t)\neq g(t)$ for some $t\in(a,b)$ and assume without loss of generality that $f^\prime(t)-g(t) = D > 0$.

By continuity there exists an interval $(c,d)\ni t$ such that $f^\prime(s)-g(s)>\frac{D}{2}$ for all $s\in(c,d)$.
Thus $\displaystyle \int_c^df^\prime(s)-g(s)\,\mathrm{d}s > \frac{D}{2}(d-c) >0$.

Hence, by contraposition, if $\displaystyle \int_{t_a}^{t_b} f^\prime(s)-g(s)\,\mathrm{d}s=0$ for any $[t_a,t_b]\subseteq[a,b]$, then $f^\prime(t)=g(t)$ for all $t\in(a,b)$.

Comment: Your third line has a $\,t\,$ there that doesn't seem to play any role afterwards...

Comment: I know, it plays a role in the first and second lines.

Comment: Then what do you need it for in the 3rd line?! And what's written there doesn't make much sense: "exists an interval $\,(c,d)\ni t\,$ s.t...." is suposed to mean that there exists an interval that contains $\,t\,$ , which is a dummy variable for integration?

Comment: Yes, that means an interval containing $t$. As I said, $t$ is defined in the first line. It is **not** a dummy variable.

Comment: Nice answer :) Although maybe a little confusing that you're using the names s and t as well in the integrals, but that's a detail.

Comment: I changed the last integral so that only $s$ is used as a dummy variable. Is it clearer now?